# Execvp linux: trying to make my shell work in C

Tags: c, linux, execvp

I'm trying to make simple shell, but with a specific condition, I have to use the following structure:

```
typedef  struct cmd_struct{
  char cmd[80];
  char args[10][80];
  int nargs;
} cmd_type;
```

Inside *cmd* I will save de main command and arguments in *args*.

Then I read from a file, different commands, and save them into and array of *cmd_type*. My program or fake shell, ask for a number and should take it from this array.

My function that executes the command looks like:

```
void execCmd(cmd_type* cmds_arg, int idxCmd){
  pid_t pid;
    printf("Father: my pid is %d\n", getpid());
    char* buff;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {  
        printf("Child process: My pid is %d\n", getpid());
           printf("-------------- Child doing exec: %s\n", cmds_arg[idxCmd].cmd);
           execvp(cmds_arg[idxCmd].cmd,&cmds_arg[idxCmd].args);
           _exit(2);
        _exit(1);
    } 
    printf("Father: Gonna wait for Child\n");

    int status;
    wait(&status);
    printf("-------------- Father: Child finished\n");

    // WIFEXITED, WEXITSTATUS Macro of the gnu lib POSIX standard to recover end status
    if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {   
        const int es = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("Father: Child Complete with exit status %d\n", es);
        if(es == 1) printf("Father: Child didn't execute any command\n");
        else if(es == 2) printf("Father: Child command was not found\n");
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I'm calling the *execvp()* system call, I'm doing it wrong. First argument I think that it is right, second one it's totally wrong.

First of all, I have a conversion problem right there, and the second problem is that the array should contain "main command", "arg1", "arg2" ... and mine only has the arguments. Am I wrong?

Is there a way to add the "main command" using services like sscanf ()? And the most important part, do I have any chance to make it work this way?

Comment: You are right, the first entry in the table is the command name. Moreover, the argument table must be NULL terminated : the last entry must contain NULL as the kernel needs it to know when the argument list stops.

Comment: Study the source code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell).

Comment: Thanks @RachidK. for tell me about the NULL parameter, I didn't now that. And thanks for show me which way follow to get the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same spirit of the answer from @pts, you can copy the parameters for *execvp()* in a dynamically allocated table:

```c
void execCmd(cmd_type* cmds_arg, int idxCmd){
  pid_t pid;
  printf("Father: my pid is %d\n", getpid());
  char* buff;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {

    int i;
    char **args = (char **)malloc((1 + cmds_arg[idxCmd].nargs + 1) * sizeof(char *));

    args[0] = cmds_arg[idxCmd].cmd;
    for (i = 1; i < (cmds_arg[idxCmd].nargs + 1); i ++) {
      args[i] = cmds_arg[idxCmd].args[i - 1];
    }
    args[i] = NULL;

    printf("Child process: My pid is %d\n", getpid());
    printf("-------------- Child doing exec: %s\n", cmds_arg[idxCmd].cmd);
    execvp(cmds_arg[idxCmd].cmd, args);
    _exit(2);
  } 
  printf("Father: Gonna wait for Child\n");

  int status;
  wait(&status);
  printf("-------------- Father: Child finished\n");

  // WIFEXITED, WEXITSTATUS Macro of the gnu lib POSIX standard to recover end status
  if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {   
    const int es = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    printf("Father: Child Complete with exit status %d\n", es);
    if(es == 1) printf("Father: Child didn't execute any command\n");
    else if(es == 2) printf("Father: Child command was not found\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `char args[10][80];`, `execvp(cmds_arg[idxCmd].cmd,&cmds_arg[idxCmd].args);` won't work (it won't even compile), because *execvp* needs a `const char*` pointer to each argument, and your `.args` doesn't have any pointers.

Something like this may work:

```
const char *p[11];  /* Contains up to 10 pointers + trailing NULL. */
cmd_type *this_cmd = &cmds_arg[idxCmd];
for (int i = 0; i < this_cmd->nargs; ++i) {
  p[i] = &this_cmd->args[i];
}
p[this_cmd->nargs] = NULL;
execvp(this_cmd->cmd, p);
```

Comment: p[] should be 12 pointers : cmd_name, at most 10 arguments and NULL. p[0] should point on  this_cmd->cmd, p[1 to nargs] = this_cmd->args[0 to nargs - 1], p[nargs + 1] = NULL

Comment: @RachidK.: Sure, `p[0]` should point to the `$0` (program name), and a good value for that is already stored in `this_cmd->cmd`. However, by reading the question it's not obvious whether this is already the case.